Put and delete methods works in Integrated pipeline mode but not in classic on my server
I have a web API application which when deployed in IIS server, PUT and DELETE methods alone does not work. But it works fine locally.
When I tried investigating more on various options like disabling WebDAV module and adding verbs in handlers. Nothing worked for me. When I change the application pool's managed pipeline mode from Classic to Integrated, it works fine.
But my clients server has to be classic for all other the legacy applications to work. Is there any work around for this?
We are using IIS-10 and mine is not a .net core application. Its .net framework 4.5 application.
My Web.config looks like this:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DBConnection" connectionString="*****" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-12.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>



Enable IIS Failed Request Tracing to see what’s going on with PUT/DELETE requests and then you know what to change next. Don’t guess.


I have a web API application which when deployed in IIS server, PUT and DELETE methods alone does not work. But it works fine locally.

In the description, what does "does not work" mean? What is the specific error message and error code (sub-status code)? I did some searching on this issue and I found these two situations which are similar to your problem: "405 method not allowed" and "500 Internal Server Error".
You mentioned that you tried disabling the WebDAV module and adding verbs in handlers. Make sure the configuration is correct, something like this:
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
        <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
        <remove name="WebDAV" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>

Based on your attempts, I think your problem is more like the second case (500 error). You can try this configuration(in modules element):
runManagedModulesForWebDavRequests="true"

More details about this attribute of <modules element>, just refer to official doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/modules/#attributes
In addition, you can try to create a new application pool and set it to Integrated managed pipeline mode. As far as I know, applications running in different application pools will not affect each other.

Yup, For PUT I got 405(Method not allowed) error and for Delete it is 404(Not found) error. The 405 error gets resolved if I change my Web.config as u said. But the 404 error for Delete still comes up.

I can't be sure how you configure each test, you need to pay attention to whether there are any restrictions on the configuration you add. For example, you have added above: <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0 ... preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />", you will find that it only works in integrated mode. Try to add something like this: <system.webServer><security><requestFiltering><verbs allowUnlisted="false"><add verb="DELETE" allowed="true" /> ...</verbs></requestFiltering></security>.
